# Aborted (core dumped) - Installing packages in R - R version 3.0.2 / Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am quite new with Ubuntu and R and I have just installed them both a couple of days back. After installing R and Rstudio successfully, I wanted to install the R package [swirl](http://swirlstats.com/instructors.html) with the command:

```
install.packages("swirl")
```

I got this problems while installing:

```
Aborted (core dumped)
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘digest’ had non-zero exit status
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x741cf)[0x7f128b51e1cf]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7f128b5b5b2c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x10a9f0)[0x7f128b5b49f0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x10cd6a)[0x7f128b5b6d6a]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(+0x926c4)[0x7f128bb206c4]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(+0x9446b)[0x7f128bb2246b]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(+0xdcddb)[0x7f128bb6addb]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_eval+0xf8)[0x7f128bb72d98]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_applyClosure+0x346)[0x7f128bb74056]
..........................................
```

And there are thousands of more code lines.

This happened too with `Rcurl`, `testthat` and `httr` continuously.

While this is happening, `Rstudio` seems to overload and turns grey.

It all ends with the this code line:

```
Aborted (core dumped)
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘swirl’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpTdWj6H/downloaded_packages’
```

I think this might have to do with the memory of my computer.
These are the specs:
Acer aspire V5-572G-6679
Memory: 5.7GiB 
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4 
Disk: 500 GB

Needless to say that when I call swirl from the library it does not work.

```
library(swirl)
Error in library(swirl) : there is no package called ‘swirl’
```

I've tried installing the packages manually but the same problem persists; Aborted(core dumped)

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: I can install swirl on my 6GB dell under ubuntu with no problem, so I'm doubting it's a memory issue. Does it crash before or after compilation of `digest`?

Comment: It does't crash. It just freezes during the installation. It might be during digest, but it also happens with the Rcurl and the others.

Comment: do the packages compile? Do you see things like `gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c aes.c -o aes.o` scrolling across the screen?

Comment: Have you tried sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcurl? If that works it might tell us if you have a problem with your gcc or with something else

Comment: I should also add you need r-base-dev installed to install packages from CRAN - `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev`

Comment: I didn't see any of that information, but I did try apt-get install r-cran-rcurl and it worked. At least it did install successfully.

Comment: I had already r-base-dev installed.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what the problem is, maybe it's worth a try to reinstall gcc.

Comment: I re installed gcc and the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. You need to install the following package to fix it.

sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

More info here : https://github.com/swirldev/swirl/wiki/Installing-swirl-on-Linux

Regards

Mathieu